# rtweet library not working, I am currently trying to scrape tweets using the search_tweets() of rtweet library but it's giving an error

Tags: r, rtweet

I am currently trying to **scrape** tweets using the search_tweets() of `rtweet` library but it's giving an error
`89 - invalid or expired token`

This used to work fine but now shoots an error. Please help me with this and suggest some workaround to this problem as I don't have the developer access to extract tweets using Twitter API

The following line of code is throwing an error

```
library(rtweet)

tweets_ds = search_tweets("#IoT", n=18000, lang="en", include_rts = F)
```

> 89 - Invalid or expired token.Invalid or expired token.

Comment: You have to create a token for authentification and call it in the function `search_tweets`. Please look at documentation

Comment: Yes, I thought as much but how to create a token for authentification is something to look into as I don't have knowledge about it. Thanks anyways!!

Comment: Look at the end of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/FAQ.html

Comment: Thanks @Clemsang, that was of some help but it also required to first create a developer account on twitter which is subject to approval. Created one and waiting for approval. Meanwhile trying to delete the tokens saved in r studio and see if that works.